# Has one looking in wrong table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-one

Im trying to set up a `has one` relationship in RoR. An agreement has one contact. In the agreement table there is a column called `contact_id`.

When i try to call an agreenment's contact like so: `<%= agreement.contact.name %>` (contact table has a column `name`) I get the error `Unknown column 'contacts.agreement_id'` Where it should be looking for `agreement.contact_id`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `contacts` table needs the foreign key migration added, i.e. you need to create a column `agreement_id` as integer.  Make sure you do `rake db:migrate` and this should work.

Remember, the FK is on the 'belongs_to' table side of the relationship.  So, an agreement `has_one` contact and contact `belongs_to` agreement.

Comment: Interesting. Will this cause issues with the fact that many different table will have a contact?

Comment: If many tables with have a contact, you need to set up polymorphic associations on the contact's `belong_to`. In the Contact model, `belongs_to :contactable, :polymorphic => true`. Then in Agreement model: `has_one :contact, :as => :contactable`. You'll also need to add a new column to the Contact model `contactable_type` (which saves the class name of the association), and rename `agreement_id` to `contactable_id`. Have a read through the Rails Guide on Associations for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Michael's answer is right; the foreign key must always be in the table for the model that 'belongs_to' another model.

However, the best answer for you may be to invert the relationship: that is, are you sure an agreement doesn't *belong to* a contact, instead of *having one* contact? If you switch the relationship, then rails will correctly know to look for the foreign key in the agreements table, and not the contact table.

[This Rails Guide has a more thorough discussion](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs_to-and-has_one) regarding the choice between `has_one` and `belongs_to`.

Comment: Good point Rob - I only provided the solution on 'getting it to' work for the OP, rather than providing a better approach.  `having_one` is a 'design' smell I'm rather weary of.  I rather sticking to more flexible `has_many, through`'s